# blueimp Gallery - bug Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, carousel, blueimp

I have a problem in internet explorer 11 with blueimp carousel, when i click in button "next" when the animation starts in the right side of carousel the next image appears and disappear, like the gif example in the site of blueimp.
Sometimes this happens also when the page refresh.
You can try in Internet explorer in https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/

[image]

Comment: Reproduce the problem by using the blueimp Gallery official demo, it seems this issue is related the plugin library, you could try to submit this issue to their [discuss forum](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/pulls). Besides, as a workaround, I suggest you could try to create the image gallery using bootstrap plugin, you could check [this article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).

Comment: @Zhi Lv - MSFT I already try, but not permit add issue for blueimp gallery in github, only a pull request